# Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$ a bounded subset. If $d(A)$ equals $r$, show that $A$ is a subset of some ball $\bar{B}(a,r)$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ be a metric space and $A \subset X$ a bounded subset. If the diameter of $A$ denoted $d(A)$  equals $r$, show that $A$ is a subset of some ball $\bar{B}(a,r)$. Give an example of a scenario where $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A$ doesn't belong to any $\bar{B}(a,r/2)$.

Let $a \in A$, then I have that $\bar{B}(a,r) = \{x \in X \mid d(x,a) \leqslant r = d(A) \}$. So essentially I would need to show that for any $x \in X$ I have that the distance between $x$ and $a$ is less than or equal to the diameter of $A$? I'm slightly confused about this I want to show that $A$ belong to an closed ball that has it's radius equal to the diameter of $A$?

Comment: Ask yourself: what's the definition of the diameter of a set in a metric space?

Comment: It's $d(A) = \sup \{d(x,y) \mid x,y \in A \}$?

Comment: You should say $A$ is a  subset of some closed ball, not "belongs to"

Answer (score 0):

With metric $\rho.$ Definition: $d(A)=\sup \{\rho (a,b):a,b\in A\}$ if $A$ is not empty. And $d(\emptyset)=0.$ And $A$ is bounded iff $d(A)\in [0,\infty).$

We must distinguish between $\overline B(a,r)=\{b: \rho (a,b)\le r\}$ and the closure $\overline {B(a,r)}$ of the open ball $B(a,r).$ For example if $X=\{a,b\}$ and $\rho (a,b)=r\ne 0$ then $r=d(A)$ but $\overline{B(a,r)}=B(a,r)=\{a\}$ and $\overline{B(b,r)}=B(b,r)=\{b\}.$

If $a\in  A$ then $\forall b\in A\,(\rho(a,b)\le d(A)=r)$ so by definition of $\overline B(a,r)$ we have $\forall b\in A\,(b\in \overline B(a,r)\,).$ That is, $A\subseteq \overline B(a,r).$

If $A$ is empty (trivial special case) then  $A$ is a subset of every set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How does it follow from $\bar{B}(a,r) = \{x \in X \mid d(x,a) \leqslant r = d(A) \}$ that $\forall b \in A$ we have that $b \in \bar{B}(a,r)$?

Comment: Because every $b\in A$ satisfies $\rho (a,b)\le r,$ which is the necessary & sufficient condition for $b$ to be a member of $ \overline B(a,r)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space.
I'll denote by $B(x,r) = \{y \in X\mid \rho(x,y) < r\}$ the open ball of radius $r>0$ around $x \in X$ and by $\overline{B}(x,r)= \{y \in X\mid \rho(x,y) \le r\}$ the corresponding closed ball.

For a non-empty subset $A \subset X$ which is bounded we can define  the diameter $d(A) = \sup \{\rho(a,a')\mid a,a' \in A\}$, which is a well-defined real number precisely because $A$ is assumed to be bounded.

If $A$ is bounded non-empty with $d(A)=r$, pick some fixed $a_0 \in A$.
Then for any $a \in A$: $\rho(a_0,a) \le d(A)  =r$ by the definition of $d(A)$ as a supremum (it's an upperbound for the set of *all* distances between points of $A$).
So by definition, $a \in \overline{B}(a_0r)$ and so $A \subseteq \overline{B}(a_0,r)$, as required.

In some cases we can say that there is in fact some $a_0 \in A$ such that $A \subseteq \overline{B}(a_0,\frac{r}{2})$, e.g. in the plane with $A=\{(x,y)\mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, where $d(A)=2$ and $A= \overline{B}((0,0), 1)$ etc.

But e.g. if we take $A=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2= 1\}$ we cannot find such a point in $A$ (!) such that all points lie within the closed ball of radius $1$ around it. Outside of $A$ we can in this case, but the problem as stated suggests to me that $a_0 \in A$ is meant..

Comment: So if $A=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2= 1\}$, then $d(A) = 1$ and if $a \in A$  we have that $A \not\subset \overline{B}(a,r/2 = d(A)/2)$?

Comment: @Dan $d(A)=2$ of course. And if $a \in A$, we have that $A \nsubseteq \overline{B}(a,1)$